# Rails: Load content text file in public after change content.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, browser-cache

I have a file text in public folder, url same like `"public/text/index.html"`

index.html

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p> hello </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I change content this file to:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p> hello World</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

When i display this file on browser (url: `"localhost:3000/text/index.html"`), It display old content.

When i clear cache on brower, it load new content. I think cause is due to cache.
How to load new content without delete on brower?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is`livereload`.

When the files change, it will auto detect, reload the server, and reload the html in browser.

Check https://github.com/guard/guard-livereload and https://gist.github.com/maxivak/6a23fc7ffe7fea00a5e2